# Rails cron with whenever, setting the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

This question will probably only make sense if you know about the whenever gem for creating cron jobs. I have a task in my schedule.rb like

```
every 1.day, :at => '4am' do
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:stop RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV}"
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:index RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV}"
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:start RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV}"
end
```

However when I update my crontab using

```
whenever --update-crontab appname --set environment=production
```

the cron jobs still have RAILS_ENV=development.  My tasks on production and development are the same right now, I just need to change the environment variable because thinking_sphinx needs to know the current environment.  Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: In my particular case (starting delayed_job) I got this working using `command "RAILS_ENV=#{@environment} #{Whenever.path}/bin/delayed_job start"`

Comment: If you run rake you may also use the `rake` command within the `whenever` context.

Answer (score -10, accepted):

I would consider using the "rake" shortcut to make it even cleaner:

```
every 1.day, :at => '4am' do
  rake "thinking_sphinx:stop"
  rake "thinking_sphinx:index"
  rake "thinking_sphinx:start"
end
```

Comment: This answer doesn't tell how to change the environment, it's just giving a way to make the task cleaner. Check Trung LE's answer for the real way to do it

Comment: Does not answer the question at all.

Comment: Please note that the `rake` command **does** in fact add the `RAILS_ENV` to the command that ends up in the `crontab`.

Answer (score 98):

Whenever doesn't detect your environment, it just defaults to using production. 
You can set the environment for all jobs using set:

```
set :environment, 'staging'
```

Or per job:

```
every 2.hours do 
  runner 'My.runner', :environment => 'staging' 
end
```

Comment: can I pass an array to the `environment` hast to set multiple environments?

Comment: This is not the correct way when we are dealing with multiple environments

Comment: What is the correct way when we are dealing with multiple environments?

Answer (score 26):

Don't write the RAILS_ENV variable. It should set it automatically.

```
every 1.day, :at => '4am' do
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:stop"
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:index"
  command "cd #{RAILS_ROOT} && rake thinking_sphinx:start"
end
```

It works in my app:

```
every 4.days do
  runner "AnotherModel.prune_old_records"
end

$ whenever --set environment=production
0 0 1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29 * * /Users/weppos/Sites/git/app/script/runner -e production "AnotherModel.prune_old_records"

$ whenever --set environment=development
0 0 1,5,9,13,17,21,25,29 * * /Users/weppos/Sites/git/app/script/runner -e development "AnotherModel.prune_old_records"
```

Answer (score 23):

For `Whenever (0.9.2)`

Use the `@environment` variable for environment check:

```
case @environment

when 'production'

every 1.minutes do

   rake "user:take_sample"

  end

when 'development'

every 1.minutes do

  rake "user:dev_sample"

  end

end
```

Comment: Note, however, that the @environment variable is always 'production' by default. You have to `whenever --set environment=development --write-crontab` when spitting out your jobs and then this answer will work.

Answer (score 16):

Something else you may want to try if you're using bundler and capistrano.

In your deploy.rb file, when you set the :whenever_command, **DO NOT** simply do this:

```
set :whenever_command, "bundle exec whenever"
```

Instead, do this:

```
set(:whenever_command) { "RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec whenever" }
```

Now, the RAILS_ENV environment variable will be available when the schedule.rb file is loaded, so in schedule.rb you can now do this:

```
set :environment, ENV['RAILS_ENV']
```

Voila!  You're ready to go.

Comment: I got this:
failed: "sh -c 'cd (REMOVED)/releases/20140127213854 && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec whenever --update-crontab (REMOVED) --set environment=production --roles db'" on (REMOVED)

Answer (score 14):

This questions has been open a long time so I thought I would share what worked with whenever 0.9.7, Ruby 2.4.0, and RAILS 5.0.1. In the previously mentioned answer there are a lot of close tries but syntax error plagues them. Below is what worked and is very simple approach.

### schedule.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/environment')
set :output, {:standard => 'log/cron_log.log', :error => 'log/cron_error_log.log'}
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

every :day, :at => '10am' do
     rake "somejob:run", :environment => @environment
end
```

### Update the crontab(dev)

```
whenever --set 'environment=development' --update-crontab
```

### Results(dev)

> 0 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /my/rails/app && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake somejob:run --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

### Update the crontab(prod)

```
whenever --set 'environment=production' --update-crontab
```

### Results(prod)

> 0 10 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /my/rails/app && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake somejob:run --silent >> log/cron_log.log 2>> log/cron_error_log.log'

Hopefully this can help someone out. 
Happy Coding this!

Comment: env :PATH, ENV['PATH'} ??

Comment: I tried to find a document on the `set` method and usage it has on the `output` log and `environment`.

Where can I find the info about it?

Answer (score 12):

Watch out if you want to pass more than one param to whenever.
You have to do it like that:

```
whenever --update-crontab appname --set 'environment=production&cron_log=/path/to/log'
```

Answer (score 6):

Latest whenever allows easy Capistrano integration. You can add following to deploy.rb:

```
set :whenever_environment, defer { stage }
set :whenever_identifier, defer { "#{application}-#{stage}" }

require "whenever/capistrano"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having an issue where environment wasn't being set up for whenever cron jobs - /usr/bin/bundle was being picked up instead of /usr/local/bin/bundle.

The solution was to add following to top of schedule.rb

```
env 'PATH', ENV['PATH']
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code at top of config/schedule.rb.

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "#{@pre_set_variables[:environment]}"
```

and update the crontab using following command.

```
whenever --update-crontab pvcnxt --set 'environment=production'
```

and then finally restart crontab using command

```
service crond restart
```

Thats it!

Final **config/schedule.rb** looks this way

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "#{@pre_set_variables[:environment]}"

 env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

 require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/environment")

 set :output, "#{Rails.root}/logs/cron_log_#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log"

 every 1.day, :at => '00:00 am' do
  command "cd #{Rails.root}/lib/tasks && rake clean__posts_table_rake"
 end
```