# Avoid loading rails environment multiple times with cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the "whenever" gem which generated a cron line for me.

```
0 5 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /projects/my_rails && rails runner -e development "Indexing::LikeIndexer.index_deltas"'
```

(The cron above is just for testing and won't be running this frequently in production =))

This and other crons (like thinking_sphinx's) require loading the whole rails environment in order to execute the code. 
([Rails cron with whenever, setting the environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070231/rails-cron-with-whenever-setting-the-environment))

Is there any gem that runs my rails environment and allows it to execute code without having to reload the whole environment?

I attempted to solve the problem with spin but it seems that spin doesn't recognize my models when I pass a file to it.

Answer (score 2):

You realize that your example is ran every day at 5 in the morning. If you can't reload your environment once per day , you might have a bigger problem that the one you try to fix :)

About your question, the only way to not reload the environment would be for a process to stay in memory with the environment loaded and then fork itself for doing the job. That's the idea behind [spork](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork) for speeding up tests.

I think it's a bit overpowered for your problem.

You could also make a rake task not depending on environment for doing your job or make a controller action and cron a curl command (with some kind of authentication mechanism of course)